# Internet speed problems using cascaded routers

Tags: wired-networking

Apologies for the long intro but think its necessary.

My house is in an area that did not have any land lines so for the past 6 years or so our only internet connection was via WIMAX. Speeds were generally poor so reluctantly we arranged our lives to fit that fact.

Now we have a high speed fibre optic internet connection provided by movistar. It is fibre to the home. The ONT (HUAWEI HG8240H) is located in the utility alongside all of my cat5 cabling terminations (feeds to different areas of the house). The Huawei has a 4 port LAN but only port 1 is enabled and the 3 others are protected. Movistar also supplied the Amper-EG-663 router.

I have attached an image to show the configuration that I have today. It basically mimics the configuration that we had with WIMAX. In that configuration now see download speeds of 307 Mbs and upload speeds of 22Mbs on my PC's in the office when connected via Ethernet (http://www.broadbandspeedchecker.co.uk/.) I am happy with that and want to maintain those Ethernet speeds.

Having got a much better provider I wanted to extent my wifi to other areas of the house (outside terrace and upstairs) whilst maintaining the high speed Ethernet within the office. My wifi needs are very limited (phones, tablets, wife's I Pad) so ultra fast wifi capabilities are of no great concern. As I said, it is the excellent Ethernet speeds in the office that I want to keep.

Following a little research on the net (I am a complete novice in this field) I discovered that I could get the extra wifi coverage that I wanted by using two old routers in a cascade mode. The routers are a TP-Link WR841ND and a Trendnet TEW-658BRM. After a lot of learning and playing I eventually managed to get them both working perfectly.

So, the plan was to move the Amper-EG-663 router into the utility room (alongside the ONT) where it could feed the existing cat5 cabling and use my two old routers elsewhere in the house. Obviously, one of the old routers would be in the office. I decided to test this plan before making any permanent changes. For the test I disconnected my PC LAN cable from the Amper-EG-663. Connected that cable to the TP-Link WR841ND (LAN to LAN) and then connected a new LAN cable between the TP-Link WR841ND and my PC. Problem is, when I do that the internet download speed drops to 32Mbs (upload remains about the same at 22Mbs. Got very similar poor results with the Trendnet TEW-658BRM.

So my plan appears to be flawed. I guess my problem could be that the TEW-658BRM is simply not capable of handling these speeds. Apparently it has 4 x 10/100 Mbps Auto-MDIX LAN ports and its specification says its an N router so I assumed it should be capable of at least 150 Mbps. Same goes for the Trendnet - just not capable?
After a little more research I found that this is a common problem with cascaded routers. Bugger. So I do not think that there are any further settings that I can make within the old routers that would address this problem - or are there?

But I also discovered gigabit Ethernet switching which, if I understand correctly, would overcome my problems, or maybe just help a little? Not sure which. In my ignorance I also assumed that a LAN to LAN connection via routers would be no different from LAN to LAN via a switch - or do switches also reduce LAN - LAN speeds?  So I do not really understand enough about this technology to move forward and therein lies my new dilemma and question(s).

But I have come up with a plan B as shown in the attached "Proposed switched configuration.jpg". Thing is, would this actually achieve what I want - maintain wired download speeds for my office PC's? And what switch(s). If this is the answer then would something like a TRENDnet TEG-S50g GREENnet Switch do the job. Or do I need something more sophisticated/capable along the lines of a fully manageable switch?

Your help and advice would be very much appreciated.

[image: Existing and proposed (switched) configuration]

Comment: what did you expect from cheap router! get new access point something strong like UBNT UNIFI :) will cover your whole area easily, and can support high speed connections...

Comment: 1. You do NOT want router cascading. 2. Your router switches are just fine, they can handle line speed. however with only 100Mbps ports you will not get 300Mbps. 3. You simply want to use the routers as switches and access points.

Answer (score -1):

The problems described could be due to two things:

1. DHCP was left on on the "old routers" and it was treating that traffic as WAN traffic thus slowing it WAY down. If this is the case its just a setting change you need (DHCP off and set a correct static IP)
2. The integrated switch in both units are just plain useless, adding two unmanaged 8 port GigE switches as per your diagram will work perfectly

While you're at it I would install two decent wireless AC access points, while it might not matter now in two years chances are your phone will be 4k as will netflix/youtube/etc and having ample wireless bandwidth to complement your lovely 1G connection will be very beneficial. Ceiling mounted Access Points can be installed and forgotten and will give you a great user experience.

Comment: Thanks. DHCP is disabled in both old routers so I think your comment #2 is most likely the cause. Are all gigabit switches equal in terms of performance (ignoring managed/unmanaged) - same goes for access points. Any personal recommendations? I was looking at these: http://www.ebuyer.com/720793-tp-link-tl-wa901nd-450mbps-wireless-n-access-point-tl-wa901nd-v4 and these: http://www.broadbandbuyer.co.uk/products/14386-trendnet-teg-s50g/   or is it always best to stay with the same brand?

Comment: And IP's in both old routers are set OK.

Comment: @RayS Personally I've found some bargain basement switches more likely to fall back to 10/100 on longer runs vs decent ones. I use TL-SG108's in several places, always found them great.

Comment: Thanks for that. I was looking at Netgear GS305. They seem to get good reviews.